# Hide expanded SearchView with text, without performing filter with empty value

Tags: android, android-toolbar, searchview, android-menu

I have Menu in Toolbar with many menuGroups. When I do a search, I filter my recyclerView, and then performing long tap, at this point I want expanded SearchView to hide and show another menuGroup (with edit buttons) to perform actions to selected items.

But when I call

```
actionView.setIconified(true)
```

in the source code it sends to my filter request to filter with query "", so I lost my filtered result and get unfiltered dataset.

How to hide\show searchView without these unnecessary for me inner calls to filter? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally figured out how to do it. To manipulating SearchView y shouldn't call

```
actionView.setIconified(true)
```

or

```
MenuItemImpl expandedItem = menu.getExpandedItem(); (our menu in toolbar)
expandedItem.collapseActionView();
```

Because it triggers ActionView to reset filtered data, as it means like "I don't need Search any more".
Instead that, you should manipulate with it's **Visibility**
and approach below works well.

```
actionView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

It doesn't make SearchView do additional calls, and just remove expanded SearchView from sight. Your data remains intact.